# My code is not showing columns horizontally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is not working, it is not showing horizontal columns. I tried everything, using sublime text 2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custome.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">col1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">col2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, right click on the page and View Page Source. Click on the link to `css/bootstrap.min.css` and see if it successfully loads the bootstrap styles. I'm wondering if this path needs correcting.

Your code works for me when I use the bootstrap CDN: http://jsfiddle.net/t2rbyj38/